Line Art Flickering in Animation (Vid below) pls help
I made an unlisted youtube video of the current render here: https://youtube.com/shorts/89_TVMOhfBs?feature=share
I'm sure you can see from the video, the flickering issue in the helmet region. This project has been months of troubleshooting and trying to make line art work. The majority of the model is back-face culled, so the only areas that have the line art modifier on them are the head/helmet/sword/body-suit. I've messed with every settings of the modifier and painfully waited for renders to show any difference for days now and I've run out of ideas. To be honest I'm on my last leg here, ready to be done with the project that was supposed to be small. I started with Cycles and switched to Eevvee because the back-face culled meshes were not rendering correctly.
If you have any wisdom to lend I'd be happy to hear from you. Thanks for you're time!!
P.S. if you have any tips on making videos render faster please throw them my way!!

